# cakephp: get values from a “car_types” table in the “users_controller.php” file?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

i have table "car_types" ,a Controller users_controller and action url

```
  localhost/carsdirectory/users/dashboard
```

in users_controller.php file i used that function

```
 public function dashboard(){

$this->set('users', $this->Car_type->find('all'));

}
```

i want to retrieve data from car_types and want to show

```
  localhost/carsdirectory/users/dashboard   in select box
```

i m getting those error

```
Undefined property: UsersController::$Car_type
```

i know, i am wrong but not able to sort out that problem

plz help me thanks in advance , vikas tyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's no relation between Users & Car_Type, you could do:

```
$this->loadModel('CarType'); // your Model name => CarType
//then
$this->set('users', $this->CarType->find('all'));
```

To populate it in selectbox, something like this should work:

```
<select>
<?php foreach($users as $key => $val) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $val['CarType']['id']; ?>">
      <?php echo $val['CarType']['car_type']; ?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it worked for me , there is no error now, could do u tell me one more thing how to fetch data from Car_types table to select box(i have two field in car_types table 1.id, 2.car_type and i want fetch data of car_type field in select box) thanks again

Comment: i have changed CarType to Car_Type bcoz model name is Car_Type ,it worked for me, thank you so much